# show current date in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime-format

i am using vb.net. and I want how to display next six days date from current date.

```
 lblDate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

This code display the current date.

Comment: did you vote down? DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, 6, Now) ????

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `AddDays` method to advance days of current date and [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) to format it. Something like this:

```
 lblDate.Text = String.Format("{0:dd MMMM yyyy}", Now.AddDays(6))
```

You can also use some other methods of [DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/497a406b.aspx) like **AddHours**, **AddMinutes** etc, but here best fit is to use **AddDays**

Answer (score 3):

```
dim sixDaysfromNow as DateTime = Now.AddDays(6)
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.adddays.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
lblDate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(6).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

dim 6DaysFromNow =  Now.AddDays(6).ToString("dd MMMM yyyy")

Comment: I think its because `DateAdd` for this question is adding unnecessary dependency on `Microsoft.VisualBasic`.